# How to convert curl request to webrequests with mfc

Tags: c++, json, request, mfc

So basically..
Im using C++ MFC, and want to do webrequests.
Therefore I use CHttpFile, CHttpConnection and CInternetSession.
The request is sent in CHttpFile->SendRequest(parameters) obviously.

On desired website, example query in CURL format looks like this:

```
curl -X PUT 
  https://url.com
  -H 'apikey: MY-STAGING-KEY' 
  -H 'authorization: Access-token: xx'
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' 
  -H 'content-type: application/json' 
  -H 'signature: xx'
  -H 'timestamp: 1507315465' 
  -d '{
    "first_name": "Max",
    "last_name": "Mustermann",
    "gender": "m",
    "email": "max.mustermann@example.com",
    "phone_country_code": "gb",
    "phone_number": "11 111 111 111",
    "street": "Street",
    "street_number": "12A",
    "zipcode": "32112",
    "city": "Londong",
    "birthdate": "07.08",
    "note": "Some note"
}'
```

Now I dont know where do I put all this information in my mfc objects?
Is it all supposed to be 1 parameter (all 1 string?) when calling CHttpFile->SendRequest()?
Or split up?
Im a little confused.

Can anybody clear it up for me? Its the first time im doing webapplication programming

Comment: This is covered in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/chttpfile-class?view=vs-2019). Did you read it? See specifically the section on [CHttpFile::AddRequestHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/chttpfile-class?view=vs-2019#addrequestheaders).

Comment: Thank u, i overlooked it. The question i now have left, is since i added all these headers, I use chttpfile->sendrequest(cstring request, ..); How should my request string i pass to sendrequest() now look like? all the requestparameters are in chttpfile already?